# Gruntfile issue with grunt-contrib-requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs, gruntjs

I'm configuring my Gruntfile and I'm stuck on something I feel should be possible but I'm not able to find the right configuration for it. I'm trying to copy my bower components to my dist on build with the grunt-contrib-requirejs module. The part I'm stuck on is keeping the folder structure in tact when copying to dist.

My app's basic structure, and dist/ should build the same way

```
Gruntfile.js
app/
  - assets/
    - bower_components/
    - js/
    - img/
    - etc/
  - index.html
```

Currently, I define each file in the copy module and it copy's them all over

```
copy: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                dot: true,
                cwd: 'app',
                dest: 'dist',
                src: [
                    '*.{ico,png}',
                    '.htaccess',
                    'partials/**/*',

                    // Bower Components
                    'assets/bower_components/requirejs/require.js',
                    'assets/bower_components/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js',
                    'assets/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
                    'assets/bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js'

                ]
            }]
        }
    },
```

But I want to eliminate this and use the paths I've already defined in main.js to copy these files over. Less hardcoded stuff, more automation.

My require task

```
requirejs: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                mainConfigFile: app + '/assets/js/main.js',
                dir: dist + '/assets/js',
                optimize: 'uglify',
                paths: {
                    modernizr: 'empty:',
                    jquery: 'empty:',
                    fastclick: 'empty:'
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

This current configuration combined with copy moves them all over properly. If I could eliminate the paths property all together and use directory properties only that would be great. If I have to copy my paths from my main.js into here thats ok... if it's the only way to do it.

Let me know if you need any more info!

Answer (score 0):

The JS files in your bower directory should be included in the optimized output of requirejs, as long as they are configured and referenced in your require js app.  If they're not referenced as dependencies, I don't think they get included.

The ico, png, htaccess and other files may need to be copied over manually.

Depending on your partials, the text plugin and hbs plugin could compile those into the optimized file I think.

I think defining empty: in paths are for using network resources (e.g. when using CDNs instead of using local bower libraries), so the paths config is probably unnecessary